# Help with solving an elliptic integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

I have the elliptic integral below, and currently I am stuck on how I can solve it, could someone please help me out:

$$\int^{\frac{L}{15}}_{0}2\pi\sqrt{\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}}{2}}dx$$

where: $a = W-\frac{0.608W^{2}}{L^{2}}x^{2}$ and $b = H-\frac{1.68H^{2}}{L^{2}}x^{2}$ ($H$, $W$ and $L$ are all positive constants).

Substituting into the initial equation:

$$\int^{\frac{L}{15}}_{0}2\pi\sqrt{\frac{(W-\frac{0.608W^{2}}{L^{2}}x^{2})^{2}+(H-\frac{1.68H^{2}}{L^{2}}x^{2})^{2}}{2}}dx$$

How can I solve the equation above?

Comment: In practice, if you have an integral this complicated, you do _not_ turn to elliptic integrals. You just use numerical integration. Elliptic integrals are mainly for theoretical work, although one of their motivations was finding the meridian arc of the Earth.

Comment: You have $P(x) = x^4 + a x^2 + b^2$ with $b > 0$ and $a^2 - 4 b^2 < 0$. For $y > 0$,
$$\int_0^y \sqrt {P(x)} \, dx =
\frac {y (y^2 + a + b) \sqrt {P(y)}} {3 (y^2 + b)} + \\
\frac {(a + 2 b) \sqrt b} 6 (2 K(m) - F(\phi \mid m)) -
\frac {a \sqrt b} 3 (2 E(m) - E(\phi \mid m)), \\
\phi = \arccos \frac {y^2 - b} {y^2 + b},
\quad m = \frac 1 2 - \frac a {4 b}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Using whole numbers
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}2=A-B x^2+C x^4$$
$$A=\frac{H^2+W^2}{2}  \qquad B=\frac{2 \left(21 H^3+76 W\right)}{25 L^2}  \qquad C=\frac{2 \left(441 H^4+5776\right)}{625 L^4}$$ and the antiderivative
$$I=\int \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}2}\,dx$$ contains, as you expected ,  the  elliptic integrals of the first and second kinds with very nasty arguments.

We can complete the square and write
$$A-B x^2+C x^4=C\left( \left(x^2-\frac{B}{2 C}\right)^2-\frac{B^2-4 A C}{4 C^2}\right)$$ Now, let
$$D=\frac{B}{2 C} \qquad \qquad E=\frac{4 A C-B^2}{4 C^2}$$ to make
$$I=\sqrt C \int \sqrt{(x^2- D)^2+E}\,dx$$

Have a look to [the monster](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B%28x%5E2-a%29%5E2%2Bb%5D%2Cx%5D).

Comment: Thank you for the help, it has been a while since I have seen such a monstrosity. The completing the square part is straightforward. But from your answer how did WA get to theirs? Is there a specific method? Also, in WA's answer, the angle for the first and second elliptical integral is complex. How is that possible? I expect a fully real answer at the end?

Comment: @user10764803. Don't worry ! This one was just a *very small* monster. This is the problem with elliptic integrals. You need a lot of patience. I used WA at the end of my work with pen and paper. In any manner, the result will be a real number.

Comment: Alright, thank you for that. One last piece of clarification, how did WA reach its answer? Can I follow the same method by hand to get the same equation? Or is it just not possible as it requires too much computational complexity?

Comment: @user10764803 Before computers, the standard reference for solving elliptic integrals was Byrd and Friedman. I have a PDF of the book, and it's been a really great help.