# Analytically solving an elliptic integral

Tags: calculus, integration, elliptic-integrals

A few days ago I had never heard of elliptic integrals. However, this morning I came across an elliptic integral in my work. The integral has the following form:

$$g(x)=\int \sqrt{x^{4}+f^{2}-2fx^{2}+h}\ dx $$

This can be simplified to:

$$g(x)=\int \sqrt{(x^{2}-f)^{2}+h}\ dx $$

In my question, $f$ and $h$ are constants. Having never worked with elliptic integrals I was (and still am) very lost on how to continue. I tried finding pieces of information online, which could help me understand how to solve the integral. I found a post of a different user on this StackExchange who had a question with a very similar integral. From the comments there I read that using the Handbook from Byrd and Friedman would help to find a solution to my question.

I found that book and I looked through it but I still cannot not come any closer to finding a solution to my question. After looking through all sorts of information on elliptic integrals I feel as lost as ever on how to solve my integral. Could someone please assist me in this?

From my understanding I somehow I have to split up the current function so that it resembles the elliptic integral of the first, maybe the second kind but I am struggling on how I could do that.

As a note, I saw in other questions programs like Wolfram Alpha can solve the elliptic integral for you. But for my case, it is important I show the solution analytically.

Comment: I find it useful to look into WHY they are called elliptic integrals i.e. what area the definite form of the integral represents :)

Comment: To obtain a result where all quantities are explicitly real, you'll have to distinguish between different cases. The comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3874812) gives an antiderivative on $(0, \infty)$ for the case $f \in \mathbb R \land h > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need symbolic integration system, such as *Mathematica*, which of course gives the answer "analytically":

$$\int \sqrt{(x^2 - f)^2 + h}\ dx =\frac{1}{3} x \sqrt{\left(f-x^2\right)^2+h}-\frac{2 i \sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{-h}-f}}
   \left(f^2+h\right) \sqrt{\frac{f+\sqrt{-h}-x^2}{f+\sqrt{-h}}}
   \sqrt{\frac{-f+\sqrt{-h}+x^2}{\sqrt{-h}-f}} \left(\sqrt{-h} F\left(i \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{-h}-f}}
   x\right)|\frac{f-\sqrt{-h}}{f+\sqrt{-h}}\right)-f E\left(i \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{-h}-f}}
   x\right)|\frac{f-\sqrt{-h}}{f+\sqrt{-h}}\right)\right)}{3
   \sqrt{\left(f-x^2\right)^2+h}}$$

Comment: But how did Mathematica reach this answer and is there maybe a simpler answer? I have read in some other questions on this forum that Mathematica provides answers which are more complex than they need to be.

Comment: I applied **FullSimplify** to the first output and it reduced the number of terms a bit, to this.  But why do you need the answer to be "simple"?  And why do you need to know how *Mathematica* reached this solution?  Computer algebra is often "non-human" or not the way humans would perform a calculation by hand.  That's fine by me!  Do you accept integrals read from a table of integrals (e.g., Gradshteyn and Ryzhik)?  If so, why?

Comment: What exactly are you integrating here? I see **no** integral sign or equals sign.

Comment: You asked for the value of a specific integral, I gave it.  but for clarity, I've amended the answer.  If someone asked "What is $2+2$?" and the answer said "$4$," would you complain that the answer didn't include a plus sign, or an equal sign??

Comment: @David G. Stork I understand both your position and the asker's complaint. Yes, the integral is very complex and would be a pain to deal with via "pencil and paper" methods. But I think perhaps some motivation as to where $\operatorname{arcsinh}$ comes from would be useful to the asker.